# Does the vagrant destroy works on current folder or globally

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am confused with `vagrant destroy` command.

The output of `vagrant status` is

```
Current machine states:

default                   running (virtualbox)
```

But I have two vagrant VMs running in Virtual box

```
MacBook-Pro:server john$ vboxmanage list runningvms
"john-servers_default_1415665580149_91312" {114ad904-8629-4c4a-9344-d685c78a8228}
"test" {a6be5689-0ac3-4ac7-845d-97f2f4022cd9}
```

Now when I do `vagrant destroy`, it says do you want to `destroy deafult VM`

Now I am not sure which machine it will destroy. I am inside `test` VM but I don't want to take risk.

I tried this `vagrant destroy test` or `vagrant destroy a6be5689-0ac3-4ac7-845d-97f2f4022cd9` but that didn't work

What is the safe way to delete VM?

Comment: @BMW but when i do `vagrant ssh` i can log into test machine and it looks fine in virtual box

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To destroy `test` VM, `cd` into the test folder and enter `vagrant destroy` - this will destroy the vagrant environment within this directory. After it is destroyed, the `default` provider will still be shown when you enter `vagrant status`, together with a `not created (virtualbox)` status.

`vagrant status` only shows one vagrant VM running in virtualbox because this command only shows the state of the underlying guest machine within that directory.

In order to see all vagrant environments, enter `vagrant global-status --prune` - this brings up the state of all the active vagrant environments no matter what directory you run this command from. You can even destroy a VM that's outside of your current directory by typing `vagrant destroy ID_TAG` by copying the ID tagged to the unwanted VM.

If you are still unsure if the right VM is destroyed, input `vagrant halt` within the `test` directory and test if the right VM is being halted. This is at the very least a reversible action in case the wrong VM is selected. But the initial solution `vagrant destroy` within the `test` directory should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`vagrant destroy` would remove, in your case, the "john-servers_default_1415665580149_91312" VM.

Vagrant look the VM ID in the directory containing the Vagrantfile in `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id`

If you want to remove the "test" VM, you can use VBoxManage.

`VBoxManage unregistervm a6be5689-0ac3-4ac7-845d-97f2f4022cd9 –delete`

Keep in mind that the `-delete` flag will remove all disks associated with this VM

Comment: but i am inside the folder of `test` vm and made that machine by using vagrant up in that folder. how can it delete other VM which is in different folder

Comment: @KKJOJ, Vagrant shouldn't touch in any other VM. Sorry, I might have come to the wrong conclusion, but Vagrant usually create a VirtualBox VM with a name like "john-servers_default_1415665580149_91312" (but it gets "john-servers" from the current dir). You can check the VM ID Vagrant is going to remove in the file .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id. It seems to me that your case is unusual, maybe you renamed your current directory after the VM was created? Or have you specified a VirtualBox "name" property in the Vagrantfile?